# Solving Three Possible Integral Form with $x$ and $y$ variables?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, education

I'm a Computer Engineer Students, and Try to get familiar with Integral, but I couldn't get the point with three form of $x$ and $y$ variables. How we can easily get the point for following equation to solve it easily?

$1) E[x]=\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^1 xdxdy $

$2) E[x]=\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^1 ydxdy $

$3) E[x]=\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^1 xydxdy $

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to show you the second one, and you can try the others yourself.

A double integral is an integral of an integral. The inner one is in terms of the first of the $\mathrm{d}...$ variables, the outer - in terms of the second. For you this means
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^1 y \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \int_{x=0}^{x=1} y \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \left(\int_{x=0}^{x=1} y \mathrm{d}x\right) \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \left(\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \mathrm{d}x\right) y \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \left(1-0\right) y \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} y \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \left. \frac{y^2}{2} \right|_{y=-1}^{y=1}  \\
 &= 0.
\end{split}
$$

**HINT FOR #3**

$$
\begin{split}
\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^1 y \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \int_{x=0}^{x=1} xy \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \left(\int_{x=0}^{x=1} xy \mathrm{d}x\right)
                      \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= \int_{y=-1}^{y=1} \left(\int_{x=0}^{x=1} x \mathrm{d}x\right)
                      y \mathrm{d}y
\end{split}
$$

Comment: @MaryamPanahi show me what you can do with the third one and i will post further hints here so you can finish it off yourself.

Comment: @MaryamPanahi please post here what you are able to do yourself. I would prefer not to do assignments for you without seeing any effort on your part

Comment: @MaryamPanahi please see the update, can you finish it now?